# Rails one model - many controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I've got a `Post` model. The `Post` could be a type of Question, Answer or Comment(similar to StackOverflow structure). For now on controller is handling requests to CRUD any type of a  `Post`. There is a convention that controllers need to be thin in Rails, and my controller doesn't seem to follow this one because of the case statements(`Post` types selection and handling) in any action. So my question: is there a way to reorganize or(even better) divide `Post` controller to handle `Question`, `Answer` and `Comment` separately, but use a common `Post` views? Any links/examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just inherit one controller from another:

One common controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  #here all the methods common for all types, if any
  def new
    @post = Post.new(:email => current_user.try(:email))
  end
  ...

end
```

Then in each controller:

```
class AnswersController < PostsController

  self.model_class = Post

  # here all specific methods
  def create
    ...
  end
end
```

And all the views you can keep in the folder `posts`, or those which are different into their own folders